# set_checkout_option Google Analytics Event - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I use Google Analytics in an E-commerce app by using firebase_analytics to track the events.

But I had a problem which is the set_checkout_option event have many counts for example 600+ per user.

The logSetCheckoutOption function is inside the initState() for each checkout steps pages.

set_checkout_option counts

[image]

The flutter code

```
Future<void> setCheckoutOption(int stepNumber, String checkoutOption) async {
    await analytics.logSetCheckoutOption(
        checkoutStep: stepNumber, checkoutOption: checkoutOption);
  }


void initState() {
    helper.setCheckoutOption(2, "Address");
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: provide code of full widget

Comment: I edited the question and insert the code